# no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}'

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, ostream

Learning C++ right now and ran into a bit of a problem. While trying to complete an example and make sure it works ran into the error:

error: `no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::istream' and 'const int') and Complex` . Here is my code.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Complex {
private:
    int real, imag;
public:
    Complex(int r = 0, int i =0) {real = r; imag = i;}

    // This is automatically called when '+' is used with
    // between two Complex objects
    Complex operator + (Complex const &obj) {
        Complex res;
        res.real = real + obj.real;
        res.imag = imag + obj.imag;
        return res;
    }

    int getR() const { return real; }

    int getC() const { return imag ; }

    ostream& aff(ostream& out)
    {
       out << real << " + i" << imag ;
       return out ;
    }

    void print() { cout << real << " + i" << imag << endl; }
};

Complex operator + (const Complex & a , const Complex &b )
{
    int r = a.getR() + b.getR();
    int c = a.getC() + b.getC();
    Complex x(r , c);
     return x ;
}


ostream& operator<<(ostream& out , Complex& c)
{
   return c.aff(out) ;
}

int main()
{
    Complex c1(10, 5), c2(2, 4);
    cout <<  c1 + c2  << endl ; // An example call to "operator+"
}
```

Not sure what is wrong with my code, can anyone help?

Comment: `ostream& operator<<(ostream& out , const Complex& c)`

Answer (score 2):

`operator +` returns by-value, that means what it returns is a temporary, it can't be bound to lvalue-reference to non-const (i.e. `Complex&`), which is the parameter type of `operator<<`.

You can change the parameter type to `const Complex&`,

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out , const Complex& c)
//                                 ~~~~~
{
   return c.aff(out) ;
}
```

and you have to make `aff` a `const` member function, to make it possible to be called on a `const` object.

```
ostream& aff(ostream& out) const
//                         ~~~~~
{
   out << real << " + i" << imag ;
   return out ;
}
```

Comment: Using the const ostream is throwing an error  , I read somewhere that , since  you are not changing anything it is always better to use const ostream& , then why the error : My code ostream& operator<<(const ostream& out , const Complex& c)
{
   return c.aff(out) ;
}

Comment: @gopalakrishna Did you make `aff` `const`? What the error message?

Comment: yes , I am getting the following error :  [Error] no matching function for call to 'Complex::aff(const ostream&) const' .The error is not because I have made aff const , but after making ostream as const reference

Comment: @gopalakrishna Ohh, don't use `const ostream&`, it's not a good idea.

Comment: but we are not changing any value , why its considered a bad practice ?

Comment: You're printing sth to `out`, so you're changing it; `out` shouldn't be `const`. On the other hand, `c` should be `const`, because it's just printed, not changed.

Comment: You are changing the state of the stream.

Comment: Suppose I removed const in both the places , then  also it does not work .After editing : ostream& operator<<( ostream& out ,  Complex& c)
{
   return c.aff(out) ;
} ostream& aff( ostream& out) 
 {
    out << real << " + i" << imag ;
    return out ;
 }

Comment: @gopalakrishna Why removes both? `out` is modified so it should not be `const`. `c` is not modified so it should be `const`.

Comment: Yes , got your point .Now I changed the operator+ function .Instead of giving of returning a value , I will return a reference .It compiles fine , but it gives garbage value , Why ? Edit code : Complex& operator + (const Complex & a , const Complex &b )
{
    int r = a.getR() + b.getR();
    int c = a.getC() + b.getC();
    Complex x(r,c);
    return x ;
} And what is the meaning that c1 and c2 are temporary

Comment: @gopalakrishna `x` is a local object, which will be destroyed when get out of the function. So the returned reference is always dangled. Returning reference to local object is a bad idea.

Comment: ok , got that , the n I will not create a new object but directly change one of the object and pass it as a reference ,like this : Complex& operator + (const Complex & a , const Complex &b )
{
    a.getR() = a.getR() + b.getR();
    a.getC() = a.getC() + b.getC();
    return a;
} ,I get an error that lvalue required as left operand of assignment.Why?

Comment: @gopalakrishna It's another question; you might post a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is waiting for a lvalue reference, and you try to print `c1 + c2` that is a temporary.

You can bind a temporary to a const lvalue reference, so you must wait for a `const Complex &c`

`ostream& operator<<(ostream& out , const Complex& c)`

Comment: After replacing the code you have mentioned , this is the error I got  : [Error] passing 'const Complex' as 'this' argument of 'std::ostream& Complex::aff(std::ostream&)' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

Comment: Yes your function is "non const", make it const, as @songyuanyao said, and it will be alright

Comment: Making a method const tells the client of your object that this function will not change any values of your object :)

Comment: Suppose I removed const in both the places , then also it does not work .After editing : ostream& operator<<( ostream& out , Complex& c) { return c.aff(out) ; } ostream& aff( ostream& out) { out << real << " + i" << imag ; return out ; }

Answer (score 0):

```
'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::basic_istream::__istream_type {aka std::basic_istream}' and '')
```

This error occurs due to use of `endl`

So omit use of `endl` in your code instead replace with '\n' whenever needed.

For example use:

```cpp
cout<<"hello\n";
```

Instead of using:

```cpp
cout<<"hello"<<endl;
```

Comment: std::endl isn't the problem here. Replacing with "\n" doesn't fix the error. (Though good point that in general it's good practice to prefer "\n" to std::endl to avoid unnecessary buffer flushes, see  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/stdendl-vs-n).

Comment: Most of time this error is generated due to buffer flushes generated by endl , So if we deal with "\n".This error can be overcome

Comment: I humored you and replaced endl with "\n", same compiler error (gcc version 9.3.0). To fix the compiler errors I ended up with the same 2 changes in the @songyuanyao answer.